# Block grid/inline-flex issue because of text length

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got a block grid of squares with text inside each. Everything works fine when there is only one line of text. More text in a square makes it move below the others and break the grid.

The other problem is that I would like one square to have an additional line of text at the top as shown by the `class="notice"`. But I can't get this to work either.

I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/382m8wzg/7/) to show more clearly what the issue is. I've had a look through this [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on flexbox but can't seem to solve the issue, not sure if it is related. Any help is greatly appreciated for a newbie.

```
 <body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="products">
      <div class="product">
        <p>Apples</p>
       <a href="#"><span class="link"></span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="product">
        <p class="notice">You won't find cheaper</p>
        <p>Best price you will find on grapes</p>
        <a href="#"><span class="link"></span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="product">
        <p>Orange</p>
        <a href="#"><span class="link"></span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="product" id="no">
        <p>Best price you will find on grapes, bananas, kiwis</p>
        <a href="#"><span class="link"></span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="product">
        <p>Orange</p>
        <a href="#"><span class="link"></span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="product">
        <p>Orange</p>
        <a href="#"><span class="link"></span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

.products {
  text-align:center;
}

.product {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 10em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 10em;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.product p {
  color: black;
}

.product p.notice {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: yellow;
}

.link {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.product:hover, div.product:focus {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need `display: inline-flex` for each of your product items. You could simply make the parent a flex container with `display: flex`, making all product items flex items.

**HTML** (no changes)

**CSS** (adjusted sections only)

```
.products {
    display: flex;                  /* establish primary flex container */
    flex-wrap: wrap;                /* enable flex items to wrap */
    justify-content: center;        /* center flex items horizontally, in this case */
}

.product {
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;

    display: flex;                   /* establish nested flex container */
    flex-direction: column;          /* stack flex items vertically */
    justify-content: center;         /* center flex items vertically, in this case */
    align-items: center;             /* center flex items horizontally, in this case */
    background-color: red;
}
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/382m8wzg/10/)

Comment: Thanks Michael! I just didn't know better, I do now. Just want to follow up on positioning `class="notice"`. Right now it sits above the text and moves upwards depending on how much text there is below. Is there a way to fix its position at the top of the square irrespective of how much text there is below?

Comment: Glad I could help. With regard to your `.notice` question, you could use absolute positioning: https://jsfiddle.net/382m8wzg/12/ ... Now, regardless of the text amount below, the `.notice` text remains fixed to the top.

Answer (score 0):

inline-flex, inline-block,inline-table,inline, img, .. all of them stands on a baseline, you may use vertical-align:

```
.product {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align:top; /* HERE */
  height: 10em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 10em;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/382m8wzg/11/